# SQL update query translation to sqldf in R

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

I have an update query that works in regular SQL, and I can't get it to work in sqldf in R.

Here is the query as it works in regular SQL

```
UPDATE Merged INNER JOIN Merged AS Merged_1 ON Merged.AccountID = Merged_1.AccountID 
SET Merged.Producttype = "FIDUCIARY 48 HRS"
WHERE (((Merged.Producttype)="SAVING ACCOUNTS") AND ((Merged_1.Producttype)="FIDUCIARY 48 HRS"));
```

I am joining the same table to itself by AccountID and showing only where the AccountID's match based on criteria. I choose a Producttype of "FIDUCIARY 48 HRS" in one table and in another a Producttype of "SAVING ACCOUNTS". I then want to update the "SAVING ACCOUNTS" to say "FIDUCIARY 48 HRS".

This is what makes most sense to me to get it to work, but it's not. I've tried other variations to declare the strings.

```
Merged = dataSegment
Merged_1 = dataSegment

sqldf("UPDATE Merged INNER JOIN Merged AS Merged_1 ON Merged.AccountID = Merged_1.AccountID 
SET Merged.Producttype = "'"FIDUCIARY 48 HRS"'"
WHERE (((Merged.Producttype)="'"SAVING ACCOUNTS"'") AND ((Merged_1.Producttype)="'"FIDUCIARY 48 HRS"'"))")
```

Of course, it's possible that this kind of query is done differently in sqldf, but I can't find much online about it.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you post the data on which you are trying to work? If you use `sqldf` to perform SQL queries on a data that is stored in R I would recommend to start learning `data.table`. The main reason is because `sqldf` will convert your data to whatever backend you configure it to before executing the queries. `data.table` is much more optimized for R.

Comment: 1. What's the error message you are getting?
2. Could you provide a reproducable example?

Comment: The error I am getting is.... Error in sqliteSendQuery(con, statement,bind.data) : error in statement: near "INNER": syntax error. I'll try and work on a reproducible example.

Answer (score 4):

Your query does not work with `sqldf` because not all DBMS support `JOIN` in the `UPDATE` clause.

But you can update your table this way:

```
sqldf(c("UPDATE Merged
         SET Producttype = 'FIDUCIARY 48 HRS'
         WHERE Producttype = 'SAVING ACCOUNTS' 
               AND AccountID IN (SELECT AccountID
                                 FROM Merged
                                 WHERE Producttype = 'FIDUCIARY 48 HRS')",
        "SELECT * FROM Merged"))
```

The `SELECT * FROM Merged` is necessary: see [sqldf FAQ #8](https://github.com/ggrothendieck/sqldf#8-why-am-i-having-problems-with-update).

---

Note that you could also use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

Merged <- Merged %>%
  group_by(AccountID) %>%
  mutate(Producttype = replace(Producttype, 
                               Producttype == 'SAVING ACCOUNTS' &
                               'FIDUCIARY 48 HRS' %in% Producttype, 
                               'FIDUCIARY 48 HRS'))
```